# I need multiple indexes of a list displayed in a text area

Tags: list, flutter, dart, indexing, foreach

I am trying to fill a list of products and other correlating items but am struggling to figure out how to get them to print out each product to its own area. I can get individual items to print out by selecting its particular index, as demonstrated in the code below.

```
children: [
  AutoSizeText(
    portProductName[],
    style: FlutterFlowTheme
            .of(context)
        .bodyText1
        .override(
          fontFamily:
              'Heebo',
          fontSize:
              24,
          fontWeight:
              FontWeight
                  .w600,
       ),
   ),
 ],
```

I am using list builder to make my list.

Here is the code that is looping through and finding the ports' product name.

```
var ports = deviceList.ports;
List portProductName = [];

(ports).forEach((e) {
  portProductName.add(e.productName);
});
```

Again, if I specify the index, such as 0,1,etc, I can get the product to show, but every instance will contain the same product name. I need the whole index, however I cannot simply write the word index and I do not know how to get all of the items in the index to show. Please help, I am new to dart/flutter and am struggling to find the correct syntax to resolve this issue.

I am using Listview Builder to create my product list. as demonstrated in the code below as well as in the provided image.

```
ListView.builder(
 physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
 shrinkWrap: true,
 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
 itemCount: deviceList.ports.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, position)
```

[image]

As requested, here is the deviceList variable.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DevicesModel deviceList = Get.find<DeviceController>. 
     ().deviceList[deviceId];
```

As requested, here is code for context.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
DevicesModel deviceList = Get.find<DeviceController>().deviceList[deviceId];
print("device index is " + deviceId.toString());
print("device id is " + deviceList.deviceId);
// print(deviceList.ports.length);

var ports = deviceList.ports;
List portProductName = [];

(ports).forEach((e) {
  portProductName.add(e.productName);
});

getSignalColor() {
  if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'yellow') {
    Color color = Colors.yellow;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'red') {
    Color color = Colors.red;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'green') {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getTempColor() {
  if (deviceList.temperatureClass == 'yellow') {
    Color color = Colors.yellow;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.temperatureClass == 'red') {
    Color color = Colors.red;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.temperatureClass == 'green') {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getStatusColor() {
  if (deviceList.statusClass == 'yellow') {
    Color color = Colors.yellow;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'red') {
    Color color = Colors.red;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'green') {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getSurgeStatus() {
  if (deviceList.surgeProtection.toString() == "1") {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getPortInfo() {
  var ports = deviceList.ports;
  var portList = [];

  (ports).forEach((e) {
    portList.add(e.productName);
  });
  return portList;
}

return Scaffold(
  // key: scaffoldKey,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 5, 0, 0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    iconSize: 40,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_return_sharp,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-.14, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        deviceList.publicId! + ' ' + deviceList.label,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style:
                            FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                                  fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.signal_cellular_alt_sharp,
                      color: getSignalColor(),
                      size: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 10,
              thickness: 2,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 514,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Expanded(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 514,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: deviceList.ports.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print('test');
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 131,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Color(0xFFEDEDED),
                                        ),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                  .fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisSize:
                                                    MainAxisSize.max,
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisSize:
                                                          MainAxisSize.max,
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .end,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        AutoSizeText(
                                                          portProductName[0],
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    24,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w600,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Column(
                                                    mainAxisSize:
                                                        MainAxisSize.max,
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .start,
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment
                                                            .end,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Text(
                                                        'Order: 3000 G',
                                                        style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                .of(context)
                                                            .bodyText1
                                                            .override(
                                                              fontFamily:
                                                                  'Heebo',
                                                              fontSize: 18,
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .w500,
                                                            ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                  .fromSTEB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisSize:
                                                    MainAxisSize.max,
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment
                                                        .start,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisSize:
                                                          MainAxisSize.max,
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .end,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Port 1',
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    12,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisSize:
                                                          MainAxisSize.max,
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .spaceAround,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .end,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Remaining: 700 G',
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    12,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Capacity: 1000 G',
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    12,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                  .fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                                              child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                                                  percent: 0.75,
                                                  width:
                                                      MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                              .size
                                                              .width *
                                                          0.89,
                                                  lineHeight: 30,
                                                  animation: true,
                                                  progressColor:
                                                      FlutterFlowTheme
                                                              .of(context)
                                                          .primaryColor,
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      FlutterFlowTheme.of(
                                                              context)
                                                          .background,
                                                  center: Text(
                                                    '75%',
                                                    style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                            .of(context)
                                                        .bodyText1
                                                        .override(
                                                          fontFamily:
                                                              'Heebo',
                                                          color:
                                                              Colors.black,
                                                        ),
                                                  ),
                                                  barRadius:
                                                      Radius.circular(8)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ));
                                // return Text('success');
                                // return _buildPageItem(position, devices.deviceList[position]);
                              }),
                        ),
                      ))),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
DevicesModel deviceList = Get.find<DeviceController>().deviceList[deviceId];
print("device index is " + deviceId.toString());
print("device id is " + deviceList.deviceId);
// print(deviceList.ports.length);

var ports = deviceList.ports;
List portProductName = [];

(ports).forEach((e) {
  portProductName.add(e.productName);
});

getSignalColor() {
  if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'yellow') {
    Color color = Colors.yellow;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'red') {
    Color color = Colors.red;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'green') {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getTempColor() {
  if (deviceList.temperatureClass == 'yellow') {
    Color color = Colors.yellow;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.temperatureClass == 'red') {
    Color color = Colors.red;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.temperatureClass == 'green') {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getStatusColor() {
  if (deviceList.statusClass == 'yellow') {
    Color color = Colors.yellow;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'red') {
    Color color = Colors.red;
    return color;
  } else if (deviceList.signalQualityClass == 'green') {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getSurgeStatus() {
  if (deviceList.surgeProtection.toString() == "1") {
    Color color = Colors.green;
    return color;
  } else {
    Color color = Colors.black26;
    return color;
  }
}

getPortInfo() {
  var ports = deviceList.ports;
  var portList = [];

  (ports).forEach((e) {
    portList.add(e.productName);
  });
  return portList;
}

return Scaffold(
  // key: scaffoldKey,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 5, 0, 0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                    iconSize: 40,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_return_sharp,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-.14, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        deviceList.publicId! + ' ' + deviceList.label,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style:
                            FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1.override(
                                  fontFamily: 'Heebo',
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.signal_cellular_alt_sharp,
                      color: getSignalColor(),
                      size: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 10,
              thickness: 2,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 514,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Expanded(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 514,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: deviceList.ports.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print('test');
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 131,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Color(0xFFEDEDED),
                                        ),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                  .fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisSize:
                                                    MainAxisSize.max,
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisSize:
                                                          MainAxisSize.max,
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .end,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        AutoSizeText(
                                                          deviceList.ports[position].productName,
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    24,
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .w600,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Column(
                                                    mainAxisSize:
                                                        MainAxisSize.max,
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .start,
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment
                                                            .end,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Text(
                                                        'Order:${deviceList.ports[position].order}',
                                                        style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                .of(context)
                                                            .bodyText1
                                                            .override(
                                                              fontFamily:
                                                                  'Heebo',
                                                              fontSize: 18,
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .w500,
                                                            ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                  .fromSTEB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisSize:
                                                    MainAxisSize.max,
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment
                                                        .start,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisSize:
                                                          MainAxisSize.max,
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .end,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Port ${deviceList.ports[position].portNumber}',
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    12,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisSize:
                                                          MainAxisSize.max,
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .spaceAround,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                                          CrossAxisAlignment
                                                              .end,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Remaining: ${deviceList.ports[position].remaining}',
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    12,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Capacity: ${deviceList.ports[position].capacity}',
                                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                                  .of(context)
                                                              .bodyText1
                                                              .override(
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                    'Heebo',
                                                                fontSize:
                                                                    12,
                                                              ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                  .fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                                              child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                                                  percent: 0.75,
                                                  width:
                                                      MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                              .size
                                                              .width *
                                                          0.89,
                                                  lineHeight: 30,
                                                  animation: true,
                                                  progressColor:
                                                      FlutterFlowTheme
                                                              .of(context)
                                                          .primaryColor,
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      FlutterFlowTheme.of(
                                                              context)
                                                          .background,
                                                  center: Text(
                                                    '75%',
                                                    style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                            .of(context)
                                                        .bodyText1
                                                        .override(
                                                          fontFamily:
                                                              'Heebo',
                                                          color:
                                                              Colors.black,
                                                        ),
                                                  ),
                                                  barRadius:
                                                      Radius.circular(8)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ));
                                // return Text('success');
                                // return _buildPageItem(position, devices.deviceList[position]);
                              }),
                        ),
                      ))),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

If these codes still don't work for you, contact me.
rasityilmaz@yaani.com

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I am already using Listview builder to build out each product. I will update my question to reflect this and demonstrate that code as well.

Comment: This suggestion results in several errors.

Comment: Can you share the deviceList variable?

Comment: As requested, I have shared the deviceList variable

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. What I want are the fields you want to show in this list.
I would like to help you if you clearly post your code and data.
I'm using a translation, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The fields are displayed in the image. Where it says water, that will be the product name. The value next to the word Order, Remaining, and Capactiy, The value next to the word Port, as well as the value in the bar to show how much of the tank is remaining. I can post all of that code, but the way it is entered is exactly like the instance for the product name. List view builder is creating the whole container that includes all of the items listed here. I can provide that code for content. By the way, your english isnt bad.